# Manually place a few vias in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, via

I  placed  a few vias manually. I get "Un-Routed Net Constraint."

How can I fix that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is just a trace going from one layer to another, why not just use a single large via? Why are you trying to use several smaller ones? And I don't use Altium, but in all software I have used, after placing them, you will have to right click and manually assign a net to the via

Comment: In Altium, a newly placed via is assigned to not connected to any net. Select the via, right click and select the net to attach to.

Comment: @MCG The image shows they've already assigned the correct net to the via. And multiple small vias  can provide a lower resistance path than one big one (which is mostly air in the middle rather than copper).

Comment: The copper the vias are in is attached to M3- but that copper is not attached to the main part of M3- as far as I can see, so it *is* an unrouted net from the point of view of the tool.

Comment: Sometimes Altium is a bit odd in what it calls out as the unconnected net, but in your second picture, you have an isolated island of M3- on the pad of that (assumedly) capacitor... is that after you deleted some of the top layer trace?

Answer (score 0):

The Via not assigned to any net(M3).So, you getting "Un-Routed Net Constraint" Error.

You can assign the net (M3) by following steps

1. Select all Vias, which is not assigned any nets.

For that,

```
 a.**Right click on the via->Find Similar Objects**
```

[image]

```
 b.**In the Find Similar Objects window, Modify NoNet -> same-> OK**
```

[image]

2. Now all unassigned Via selected and the PCB inspector window will appear.

There have to assign the Net name(M3) from No Net.and close the window.
[image]

Now, The Error cleared.